# TCPDF Setting Fixed Border

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I am converting a HTML in PDF using tcpdf using PHP.

Kindly view the output here for the below given content.

[image]

```
<div style="text-indent: -76.5pt; margin: 0in 54.9pt 0pt 76.5pt;"><strong><span style="font-size: small;"><span style="text-transform: uppercase;">Motion with Constant Acceleration</span></span></strong>&nbsp;</div>
<p style="text-indent: -76.5pt; margin: 0in 54.9pt 0pt 76.5pt;"><span style="text-transform: uppercase;">Overview<br />
</span><br />
The concepts of displacement, velocity, and acceleration are very important to master.&nbsp;The study of acceleration provides an important link between kinematics (the study of motion) and dynamics (the study of the causes of motion).&nbsp;The study of acceleration also plays a key role in understanding such concepts as gravity, circular motion, harmonic motion, electricity and magnetism. The simplest case of acceleration to analyze mathematically is that for an object moving with a constant acceleration. This is the situation for any object experiencing a constant force.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
<div style="text-indent: -76.5pt; margin: 0in 54.9pt 0pt 76.5pt;" class="rteindent1">
<div style="text-indent: -76.5pt;"><span style="font-size: 9pt;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1.&nbsp;&nbsp; You will measure the position of at&nbsp;various&nbsp;time intervals as it moves down an&nbsp; inclined track due to the force of &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;gravity. A tape timer will be used to measure time intervals of 0.1 s and the corresponding displacement in position.</span></div>
<div style="text-indent: -76.5pt;">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="text-align: justify; text-indent: -13.5pt;"><span style="font-size: 9pt;">2. Next, you will determine the average&nbsp;&nbsp; velocity and time for several points along the carts path of motion from the tape timer data.</span></div>
<div style="text-indent: -76.5pt;">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="text-align: justify; text-indent: -13.5pt;"><span style="font-size: 9pt;">3. Finally, you will determine the acceleration of the cart down the track from a plot of the average velocity vs. time. Using trigonometric principles, you will verify that the acceleration is due to the force of gravity.</span></div>
</div>
```

Kindly see that **in the output contents are out of the border**. I find out that by ***giving text-indent:-76px style this is happening.*** `Even *if i give that style* content should not go out of the page`... Wat should be done to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be ignoring the margin. 
have you tried specifing all margins like this (sometimes TCPDF tends to ignore things):

```
margin-top: 0in;
margin-right: 54.9pt;
etc...
```

Another thing that comes to my mind: are you sure that TCPDF supports 0in as a notation?Have you tried changing that to 0pt?